# ggplot & bold : how can I make bold the values in the axis bold?

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, axis, bold

I'm trying to make bold the values on the axis of a plot, but i'm failing!

I'm only finding guides to make the label of the axis bold, but it is not what I'm looking for...

do you know what is the right command?? If in the x-axis i have ( 1, 2, 3, 4), I need to have them bold or with a greater size

I have already tried

```
theme(axis.text = element_text(face="bold"))
```

```
theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold")
```

but none of them works

this is my code

```
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(`Provincia`, pcty), y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", size = 15))+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F76900","#4B0082")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,26,1))+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(format(round(pct1, digits =1)),"%"), y = pcty), hjust = 1, colour = "white", fontface = "bold")
```

and this is the plot.. I need to have the characters on the left in bold or bigger
[image: plot]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Have you tried https://datavizpyr.com/how-to-make-axis-text-bold-in-ggplot2/? Are you adding the `theme()` to your plot with `+` or are you just calling it as a separate function? What exactly is the code you are running?

Comment: hi @MrFlick i've tried many things... i've uploaded the code and the plot... can you take a look?

Comment: You are setting `them_classic()` which is resetting the theme. The order in which you add information to your plot matters. Move your `theme()` part to after the `theme_classic()` so those setting don't get overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a different theme like `theme_classic`, make sure your first call that theme before the `theme` function like this:

```r
df = data.frame(x = c(1:4),
                y = c(1:4))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = x)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", size = 15))
```

[image]

---

You could use `axis.text.x` with `element_text` to make the labels bold and change their `size` like this:

```r
df = data.frame(x = c(1:4),
                y = c(1:4))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = x)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", size = 15))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: hi @Quinten and thank for the answer... i've tried in this way, but it doesn't work... i've uploaded the cose in the code in the question... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @io_boh, Please see check my updated answer! You should first call `theme_classic` before the `theme` function.

Comment: now it works! I didn't know thank! Thank you